# jQuery: missing ] after element list

Tags: jquery

I have that error in the code below. What's wrong ? I have no ideas left.

```
missing ] after element list
   [object XMLHttpRequest]

   $(function () {
            setInterval($.post('/Sale/UpdatePrice', 
                                {SaleId : @Model.Id},
                                function(data){
                                    $('#mPrice').val(data);    
                                }
                            )
                        ,5000); //refresh every 5 seconds
        });


    C#
    public JsonResult UpdatePrice(int SaleId)
    {
        ...

       return Json(NewPrice, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //NewPrice is a decimal 
                                                              number
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for being Capt. Obvious here, but it seems that the JSON returned is missing a ] to end the array, Can you please post the JSON?

Comment: the NewPrice object is a decimal number

Comment: I think your JSON is still returning as an array containing a decimal, and missing the bracket `[1.234`

Comment: Yeah I would still like to see the json, you can use fiddler to get it

Comment: Theres your problem, it needs to be a punctiuation or JSON will parse the string as a list

Comment: You could set your culture settings if you wanna do it properly. or just replace the comma with a punctuation mark to test that it works

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't it need to be in a closure,

```
$(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.post('/Sale/UpdatePrice', 
            {SaleId : @Model.Id},
            function(data){
                $('#mPrice').val(data);    
            }
        )}
    ,5000); //refresh every 5 seconds
});
```